# How to use laravel collection to get array of matched value from multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, laravel-5, laravel-collection

I have response like:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
            [0] => Array (
                    [Product] => 'Product1'
                    [Total] => $10
                   )
            [1] =>  Array (
                     [Product] => 'Product2'
                     [Total] => $50 
                   )
           )    
    [1] => Array (
           [0] => Array (
                   [Product] => 'Product1'
                   [Total] => $20
                  )
           [1] => Array (
                   [Product] => 'Product2'
                   [Total] => $30 
                  )
           )
    [2] => Array (
           [0] => Array (
                   [Product] => 'Product1'
                   [Total] => $0
                  )
           [1] => Array (
                   [Product] => 'Product2'
                   [Total] => $10 
           )
      )
 )
```

I want to get array of `Total` of `Product1` but only using [laravel collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections).

I have tried :

```
$data = [];
    $collection = collect($monthly_usage_data)->each(function ($item, $key) {
            $data['Total'][$key] = str_replace('$', '', collect($item)->where('Product', 'Product1')->pluck('Total'));
            echo str_replace('$', '', collect($item)->where('Product', 'Product1')->pluck('Total'));
    });
```

When i print $data it shows blank array; When i echo inside each it ll give `["10"]["20"]["0"]` .

Can somebody tell me right way to use collection to get array of `total` of `product1`

Comment: `collect($item)->where('Product', 'Product')` looks like a problem to me.  I think you may be relying on collections too much instead of just using array map functions on this.

Comment: sorry my bad that was product1 `collect($item)->where('Product', 'Product1')`

Answer (score 1):

Remember that functions have their own scopes.  $data in the global scope is not the same as $data inside your function unless you import it.

You can import variables into anonymous functions with use:

```
function ($item, $key) use ($data) {

}
```

Comment: still getting blank array

Comment: Then that means your function isn't executing

Comment: i have echo that value its printing `["10"]["20"]["0"]`

Comment: Add an update to your code (don't overwrite your existing code), add it below it

Comment: @Omi I see you made an edit but I still don't see you importing $data

Comment: i have not updated that in question but internally i m did that here just added echo

Comment: @Omi ok, well if you imported $data properly and the echo is being hit, then $data can't possibly be an empty array because you're assigning at the very least a total key to it...

Comment: right my array was empty, i have assigned value to array now getting proper values but my concern is it looks like complex is there another easy way or methods do to

Comment: still not getting empty array for `Total`

Answer (score 0):

generally you can use this :

```
$totals = $collection->where('Product', 'Product1')->mapWithKeys(function ($item) {
    return $item['Total'];
});

$totals->all();
```